# Scrapy not getting date as item argument

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code, i want to add as an item argument the current date, i've found different solutions on the web but i keep getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable or TypeError: 'ItemMeta' object does not support item assignment

my code is this:

```
datascrape = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") #also tried str(datetime.datetime.today())
item['dataoggi'] = datascrape() #i tried also datascrape without ()
```

How can i get as an item argument the date of the scrape?

Updated code:

```
from bot.items import botitem
import time

class NetbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "netbot"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://example.com'
    )

    def parse(self, response):

        stati = response.xpath('/html/body//div/table/tbody//tr//td//img//@title').extract()
        numeri = response.xpath('/html/body//div/table/tbody//tr[2]//td/text()').extract()
        for i in range(1, len(stati)):
            item = botitem()
            datascrape = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            botitem['dataoggi'] = datascrape
            botitem['state'] = stati[i]
            botitem['number'] = numeri[i]

        print botitem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

You should not be calling `datascrape` - it is a string:

```
item['dataoggi'] = datascrape
```

> TypeError: 'ItemMeta' object does not support item assignment

This, means you are trying to add a field to an Item class, not instance. Replace:

```
item = botitem()
datascrape = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
botitem['dataoggi'] = datascrape
botitem['state'] = stati[i]
botitem['number'] = numeri[i]
```

with:

```
item = botitem()
datascrape = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
item['dataoggi'] = datascrape
item['state'] = stati[i]
item['number'] = numeri[i]
```

Comment: i tried also without the parenthesis as stated in the comment in part of the actual line

Comment: @GGA okay but where is `MyItem` coming from? Can you share the complete code you have so far?

Comment: @GGA this is what I meant. See how you are using the `botitem` here, for example: `botitem['dataoggi'] = datascrape`. It should be `item['dataoggi'] = datascrape`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `botitem` is a class object, so you must have it declared first. You may define as show below:

```py
from bot.items import botitem
import time
class NetbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "netbot"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://example.com'
        )
    botitem=botitem()

    def parse(self, response):

    stati=response.xpath('/html/body//div/table/tbody//tr//td//img//@title').extract()
    numeri = response.xpath('/html/body//div/table/tbody//tr[2]//td/text()').extract()
    for i in range(1, len(stati)):
        datascrape = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        botitem['dataoggi'] = datascrape
        botitem['state'] = stati[i]
        botitem['number'] = numeri[i]

    print botitem
```